# What's that mystery beat that's present in Spanish and Middle Eastern music?

Tags: terminology, rhythm, beats

Believe it or not, I've been trying to find the name of this specific beat since I was 7 or 8 years old. Here are some examples of it:

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it has a different name in each culture that uses it.

Comment: [BTW, those two examples are not equivalent…however] There used to be a VST instrument called Darbuka, by Wizoo [the demise of which I still sadly miss] which had accurate names for all this stuff i can only call 'camel riding' & I don't mean that impolitely, I just have no better name & I wish I did. I used to have neighbours who ran a drum troupe. They were great, they'd have known… they're not there any more either. For nostalgia, read about it - https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/wizoo-darbuka-latigo It was brilliant.

Comment: What you do have in that magazine article is a list of over 20 named styles you could investigate.